# BS4 getting value from different div with the same class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a site that has two types of prices, normal price, and discounted prices.

Normal Price HTML:

```
<p class="plp__price__325EX">
   <span aria-label="$29.99">$29.99</span>
</p>
```

Discounted price HTML:

```
<p class="plp__price__325EX plp__salePrice__2ExZ2 plp__price__325EX">
       $11.99 // trying to get this price
       <span class="plp__priceStrikeThrough__2MAlQ plp__price__325EX">$15.99</span>
    </p>
```

Normal price code:

```
try:
    normal_price_element = item.find('p', {'class', 'plp__price__325EX'})
    normal_price = normal_price_element.find('span').text
except:
    normal_price = ''
```

Discounted price code:

```
try:
    disc_price = item.find('p', {'class', 'plp__salePrice__2ExZ2'}).text
except:
    disc_price = ''
```

The only difference between these code snippets is the class name. The problem is that the span in the `p` class contains `plp__price__325EX` so the normal price code will run when it shouldn't and get the normal price instead of the discounted price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this document:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<p class="plp__price__325EX plp__salePrice__2ExZ2 plp__price__325EX">
       $11.99
       <span class="plp__priceStrikeThrough__2MAlQ plp__price__325EX">$15.99</span>
</p>

<p class="plp__price__325EX">
   <span aria-label="$29.99">$29.99</span>
</p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
```

Then you can use lambda function to locate `<p>` tag that contains only one class `plp__price__325EX`:

```
# find <p> tag that contains only *ONE* class="plp__price__325EX"
normal_price = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "p"
    and tag.get("class", []) == ["plp__price__325EX"]
)

dis_price = soup.find("p", class_="plp__salePrice__2ExZ2")


print(normal_price.get_text(strip=True))
print(dis_price.contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
$29.99
$11.99
```

---

Or you can use CSS selectors:

```
normal_price = soup.select_one(
    "p.plp__price__325EX:has(>[aria-label])"
).text.strip()
dis_price = soup.select_one("p.plp__salePrice__2ExZ2").text.split()[0]

print(normal_price)
print(dis_price)
```

Prints:

```
$29.99
$11.99
```

Comment: Impressive.  You really know your BS :>p

Comment: Ha I was just going say